# "А на дню чего только не принесёт толпой, текущей ручейком под нашими окнами!" - всё ли понятно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Так у меня появилась подружка – старушка напротив. Мы с ней вместе
>   любопытствуем, если что на улице происходит. **А на дню чего только не
>   принесёт толпой, текущей ручейком под нашими окнами!** А утром на
>   рассвете и вовсе – в небо распахнёшь старые деревянные рамы и зыришь.
>   Хорошо! Окна тут придуманы как лоджии. Ты заходишь в оконную нишу,
>   подходишь вплотную к внешней стене и можешь очень долго стоять, ловко
>   опираясь локтями на лёгкие кованые перила. В почтенных домах у откосов
>   стены устроены две скамеечки напротив друг друга – чтобы сидеть
>   рядышком и переговариваться. Итальянцы обожают торчать в окнах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все понятно, но именно так, мне кажется, не пойдет.
Надо — или **что-то приносится** толпой, или чего-то **приносит толпа**.

А на дню что только не приносится толпой, текущей ручейком...
А на дню чего только не приносит толпа, текущая ручейком...

В остальном — красиво.

Answer (score 1):

***А на дню чего только не принесёт толпой, текущей ручейком под нашими окнами!***

1) *Принесло, принесет* — **обычные безличные формы** (лодку принесло ветром), исправлять не надо.

2) Предложение в общем понятное, немного необычен детерминант ***на дню,*** который, как правило, используется в сочетаниях (несколько раз на дню).

3) Глаголы ***зырить*** и ***торчать***, **как мне кажется**, не подходят по стилю к этому тексту, их бы надо заменить.

Лучше использовать или нейтральный стиль, или высокий (книжный)   в ироническом смысле, например,  ***созерцаешь***.

Или так: Итальянцы обожают "присутствовать" ("отдыхать") в окнах. Или современный сленг: зависать, западать.

Ну что-нибудь, только не торчать и зырить.

Comment: Извините, а можно спросить? Принесло ветром (что? В. п.) лодку. Приносится толпой (что?) чего (Р. п.). Разве так правильно? Или я чегой-то не понимаю.

Comment: А можно спросить? Ваш вопрос иронический, судя по его форме? Кстати, Ваш ответ принят, так что, возможно, Ваша позиция более правильная, хотя я в этом не уверена.

Comment: Зря, зря Вы так жестко. Я действительно хотела понять (без какой-либо иронии), почему Вы считаете Р. п. допустимым. "Принятие" вопроса его автором никоим образом нельзя считать абсолютной истиной (таких случаев — пруд пруди). Ваши знания, опыт и умение отстаивать свою точку зрения (без кавычек!) заставляют меня чувствовать себя дилетантом (что верно) и школьницей (что неверно). Если я к Вам н е п р а в и л ь н о обратилась, ещё раз — извините. P. S. **Чегой-то** — так говорила моя бабушка (1909 г. р.), я и привыкла.

Comment: Тогда извините меня, Римма.  Я уже собралась ответить, но споткнулась на чтой-то. (Теперь мне везде кажется ирония, где ее и нет). Потом я решила, что я неправа, что ответить всё-таки нужно, но опять не получилось. Ведь автор приняла ответ, согласилась с Вами, а вдруг  Вы правы. Поэтому я стала сомневаться и даже задала вопрос о похожем предложении на форуме, да только никто не отвечает. Нужно хотя бы примеры у классиков поискать.

Comment: Я рада, что нашлись и буковки, и точки над ними.

Answer (score 1):

*А на дню чего только не принесёт толпой, текущей ручейком под нашими окнами!*

По-моему, ничего править не нужно: родительный падеж здесь обусловлен присутствием отрицательной частицы НЕ. Вспомним правило:

> Какой падеж нужен при отрицании? Существительное, относящееся к
>   глаголу с отрицанием, может иметь форму родительного или винительного
>   падежа, например: не прочитал этой статьи – не прочитал эту статью.
>   Трудность заключается в том, что в одних случаях тот или иной падеж
>   является предпочтительным, а в других существует равная возможность
>   употребления как родительного, так и винительного падежа. Когда нужен
>   родительный падеж?
>
> • При сочетании с глаголом не иметь.
>
> • При наличии слов никакой, ничей, ни один:
>
> • При глаголах восприятия, мысли.
>
> • Если существительное имеет отвлеченное значение.
>
> • **Если в качестве зависимого слова используется местоимение: не допущу
>   этого; не делайте того.**
>
> • Если перед глаголом или непосредственно перед именем есть
>   усилительные частицы и, даже: Отправлялись за покупками втроем, но
>   Любе и слова сказать не удавалось, старики сами все выбирали (Кетл.);
>   Руки дрожат и не держат даже плошки с лекарством - не удержать им и
>   книги (Сарт.);
>
> •   При наличии повторяющегося союза ни... ни: не читает ни книг, ни
>   газет.
>
> • В некоторых устойчивых сочетаниях: не играет роли, не производит
>   впечатления, не обращает внимания, не уделяет внимания, не приносит
>   ущерба, не придает значения, не вызывает сомнения, не принимает
>   участия и т. д. А также: не говоря (не сказав) худого слова; не
>   сводить глаз с кого-чего-л.; не находить себе места; плетью обуха не
>   перешибешь.
>
> Когда нужен винительный падеж?
>
> • Если отрицание не стоит не при глаголе, а при другом слове: не очень
>   люблю стихи, не всегда читает книги, не вполне усвоил предмет (ср.:
>   люблю стихи, но не очень; читает книги, но не всегда; усвоил предмет,
>   но не вполне).
>
> • Если при глаголе кроме данного существительного должно быть еще одно
>   зависимое существительное или прилагательное: он не считает книгу
>   интересной; не прочитал статью за вечер; не обеспечили регион
>   электроэнергией; Разве вы не считаете эту практику полезной?
>
> • Если существительное относится к инфинитиву, отделенному от глагола
>   с отрицанием другим инфинитивом: он не хочет начинать писать мемуары
>   (ср. он не хочет писать мемуаров и мемуары).
>
> • При наличии в предложении местоимений, указывающих на определенность
>   объекта: Эту песню незадушишь, не убьешь; он не решил эту задачу (ср.:
>   он не решал задач).
>
> • При наличии после существительного придаточного предложения со
>   словом который: Он не прочитал книгу, которую я ему дал.
>
> • При одушевленном существительном или при имени собственном.
>
> • Если отрицание входит в состав частицы едва не, чуть не, чуть-чуть
>   не.
>
> • В собственно отрицательных предложениях типа Некому показать работу;
>   негде опубликовать статью.
>
> • В некоторых устойчивых сочетаниях: Не морочь мне голову; Не скаль
>   зубы.

В остальных случаях существительные в описываемых конструкциях

> обычно можно использовать в форме и родительного падежа, и
>   винительного падежа.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=67

**У нас зависимое слово - местоимение (чего только), значит предпочтителен родительный падеж.** Он здесь вносит этакий шарм старины, народного языка. Всё понятно. *Чего только не принесёт* - безличная конструкция с пассивным субъектом (толпой), нормальная разговорная конструкция.

А вообще, на тему родительного падежа при отрицании Ежи Лисовский интересную статью написал:
http://newslab.ru/article/178928

А вот просторечие **зырить** мне тоже не нравится. **Обожают торчать** - ещё куда ни шло, а **зырить** - вульгарщина.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ второй** (почему я теперь сомневаюсь в правильности предложения)

***На дню чего только не принесёт толпой, текущей ручейком под нашими окнами!***

1) **Грамматика (выбор Р.п.) правильная, но как ее объяснить**

Если и связывать Р.п. с отрицанием, как предлагается,  то не с отрицанием вообще, а с местоименной формой ***чего не***, которая обычно используется в подобных предложениях и в которой отрицание совмещено с количественно-разделительным значением: ***Чего только не было! Чего она только не принесёт!***

Потому что **одно отрицание не может задавать Р.падеж однозначно,** например:  *Сегодня  они не принесли свои работы* (В.п.). *Лодку* (В.п.) *так и не принесло ветром, как мы надеялись.*

Как мы видим, отрицание есть, а Р.п. нет.

**2) Об отрицании**

Вообще идея отрицания для Р.п. очень проста: **есть предмет (И.п.)  – нет предмета (Р. п.).**  Здесь относительно Р.падежа нет никаких сомнений.

Далее по этому же принципу  делается выбор для переходных глаголов: **вижу предмет (В.п.) – не вижу предмета (Р.п.).**

Но ведь отрицание-то относится в этом случае  к действию, а не к предмету, и поэтому **винительный падеж успешно конкурирует с родительным.**

Правила Розенталя  для выбора Р.п. или В.п. чисто **эмпирические, они обобщают практику применения этих  падежей.** (Там на пару десятков правил нет  общей идеи, а если и есть, то она не сформулирована).

3) **Но вернемся к нашему предложению.**

Итак, грамматика у него верная, но ведь **о грамматике и не было речи.** Автор спрашивал, насколько **понятно** звучит предложение для читателя.

И вот здесь  начинается самое интересное. Сомневается в предложении автор, и отвечающий на вопрос  также не считает его правильным и понятным. Да и мне в первом прочтении оно показалось **немного шероховатым**, хотя грамматика  вопросов не вызывала.

**Так в чем же дело?** Попробуем  составить похожее предложение, например:  ***В этот уголок озера чего только не принесёт ветром.*** Вроде бы всё понятно.

4) И тогда остается под вопросом лексическая сочетаемость – ***чего только не принесёт толпой.***

Значение у «толпы» переносное (это всё-таки не ветер), да и    форма Т.п. может обозначать **не только субъект действия, но  и обстоятельство образа действия**, например,  в сочетании *проноситься*  (как?) *толпой*.

К тому же дальше следует обособленный определительный оборот, в котором также присутствует **обстоятельственная форма Т.п**. ***ручейком***.

5) **Вывод**

И вот всё это вместе взятое и создает, как мне кажется, **проблему с пониманием текста,**  а из этого следует, что лучше **отказаться** от безличной формы:

***На дню чего только не принесёт толпа, текущая ручейком под нашими окнами!***